# CSS hover state - looping effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

This code gives a nice effect when hovered over the txt. The shakiness looks cool. But it only happens while slowly moving the mouse, if the mouse is stable the hovered style takes over.

So is there any way to retain the shakiness(or rapid switching, for lack of words) even when the mouse is stable, maybe atleast 5 times b/w the hover style and non-hover style, with CSS3. I know with JS it can be possible, but like to know the CSS method though little JS wont hurt.

HTML

```
<div id="intro"><h1>Lorem Ipsum<br>dolor</h1></div>
```

CSS

```
#intro {
      font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;}

#intro:hover {
      font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h9306qq5/

--UPDATE

Or for that matter an effect which transitions b/w the non-hovered style and hover-style, for a set interval or number, when hovered.

Comment: Fonts seems to be funny. It was really nice locally.

Comment: add width:  400px; height: 200px; to avoid flickering. This is happens becouse different font has different features. details here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html. That is why is u hover from up where is no flickering but if u hover from bottom side there is.

Comment: @simar flickering is what caused the effect to look cool. See question update

Comment: not exactly. open firebug and u will see that height of element is changing on hover. this is unpredictable behaviour and undesireable. It is uncontrolled side effect.

Comment: @simar I know it is a side-effect, but if properly done it should look as if the styles is transitioning back and forth b/w two styles, the stable non-hovered style and the hover style, for a set duration or count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get your goal by doing ot simply with jquery.
It should be something like:

```
$('#intro').on('hover', function() {
  var that = $(this);
  that.css('font-family', "'Pacifico', cursive;");
}, function() {
  var that = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() { 
    that.css('font-family', "'Lobster', cursive;");
  }, 500);
});
```

You can increase the time between the switch by adjust the timeout time.

Here is a fiddle without included fonts, to get it working: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3r60dbby/)

Comment: it has no effect because you kept your hover, additional there is an error with @font-face: http://jsfiddle.net/h9306qq5/3/

Comment: checkout the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3r60dbby/ its working now because there is no error with the fonts, this are standard fonts.

Comment: but this is not rapidly fluctuating, for a set duration or count, b/w the non-hovered font(lobster) and the hovered font(Pacifico) and finally setting on the hovered font(Pacifico). If you look at my original fiddle there was this flickering effect. Even though it was a side-effect, but if properly done it should look as if the styles is transitioning back and forth b/w two styles.

Comment: You can achieve it by adding more timeouts, but i can not recommend it, here would be a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3r60dbby/2/ You can play with times to make the flickering faster.

Comment: Why do you say `not recommend it`

Comment: putting so many time outs behind each other or putting a sleep in a loop arent nice ways to solve a problem. As soon as the project, website will increase on lines and scripts it could be possible that this can create issues. If you only have a simple website, you dont need to worry. But this is not a solution for huge projects ;-)

Comment: I hope this can also trigger some external actions like playing a background video, until the mouse is over the element. Also, can a click action support the same effect?